# parent div draggable not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#move" ).draggable({ 
containment: 'parent'

  stop: function(event, ui) {
      var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
      var pos_y = ui.offset.top;
      var username = ui.helper.data('username');

      //Do the ajax call to the server
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "coordsave.php",
          data: {x: pos_x, y: pos_y, username: username}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }); 
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong? When I add containment: 'parent' it doesn't working. When I remove it everything is working but I need to make dragging only inside div...

Comment: Did you add a comma after 'parent'?

Comment: omg no haha my nick says all